# PhpStorm - Change deployment server for a project

Tags: phpstorm

How can I change the deployment server for a certain project? I have two remote servers.

I tried it by setting the default remote server to the other server but the old server is still getting used. I also noticed that when I try to manually sync a file, then only the old server is suggested.

I am using v 2020.3

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem was, that the "Mapping" was not set.
After setting up the mapping, it works as expected.